# What is the definition of source code and code?

Tags: definition

What is the exact definition of source code and code?

```
printf("hi\n");
```

Is this a source code or a code?

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("hi\n");
}
```

This is definitely a source code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Source code** is generally understood to mean programming reports created by a programmer with a text editor or visual programming tool and then stored in a file. The object code usually refers to the output, the compiled file, which is produced when the source code is compiled with a C compiler.
The **code** file contains a sequence of algorithms that can be read by a machine running on a computer CPU. The operating system or application software is usually in the form of a compiled object code.

**Objectives of the source code**
Beyond providing the foundation for software development, source code has other important purposes. For example, software installations can be easily customized if skilled users need access to the source code.

Meanwhile, other developers may use source code to create programs similar to other operating systems - which would be tricky without coding.

Allows programmers to access source code to contribute to their community, either by sharing code for learning codes or by recycling it into other parts.

There are various programs for generating source code. Here is an example source code for the Hello World project in C language:

```
/ * Hello World Program * /

#Include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
printf ("Hello World");

}
```